# How to return only one result from sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following database table:

```
LNr OrderNr Ident Amount
1   128     3     123.00
2   128     14    200.00
3   1290    3     300.00
4   13400   3     637.00
```

I want to calculate the sum of the `Amount`-fields where `Ident` equals 3, but not 14 at the same time. So I want the database server to return only row number 3 and 4(where `OrderNr` = 1290 and 13400).

I tried:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM table WHERE Ident = '3'
```

But that does not work of course, because this also returns row 1 (which I do not want because `Ident` equals 14). I tried some other queries, but to no avail.

Comment: where there doesn't exist a row for the same `OrderNr` with a different `Ident`

Comment: What *is* the value that you get for `SUM(Amount)` in that query?  I am expecting the answer to be `123 + 300 + 637 = 1060.`  What do *you* get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add another `not exists` condition:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) 
FROM   mytable x
WHERE  Ident = 3 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable y
                   WHERE  x.OrderNr = y.OrderNr AND y.Ident = 14)
```

Comment: `y.Ident <> 3)` probably, but yeah.

Comment: @DanielE. OP states that "but not 14" - seems that the requirement is to specifically exclude 14. If the requirement is just to exclude any `OrderNr`s that have `Ident`s that aren't 3, you're right, and the condition should be `y.Ident <> 3`.

Comment: It's not extremely clear from the question, just seems to me that's what OP tried to say. you got my +1 :).  EDIT: Rereading they did specify 14, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is to further qualify your WHERE clause, by either excluding row 1, or including just row 3 and 4.  You need additional filtering.  There must other tables joined to that table that should allow you to filter gracefully based on whatever business rules you have defined.

Answer (score 1):

Or you may do that using `not in`

```
SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM mytable
WHERE Ident=3 AND OrderNr NOT IN (SELECT OrderNr
                                  FROM mytable
                                  WHERE Ident=14)
```